# How can I open a .pkl file in pycharm?

Tags: python

I am trying to open a .pkl file by this code:

```
with open('./PPG_FieldStudy/S1/S1.pkl', 'rb', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

However, there is an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What should I do to open it?

Comment: removing the encoding='utf8' part when opening the file might fix it

Comment: I think it is `utf-8` not `utf8`

Comment: I've tried both change utf8 to uft-8 and remove it, this error still exists